# Shared Object not loading, gives segmentation fault on dlopen

Tags: shared-libraries, d, dlopen

I have a lot of code that was written on 32 bit machine. Now I've upgraded to 64 bit, and it won't load shared objects. The shared object is compiled for 32 bit (using `-m32` flag for DMD), and so is the host application.
This is the shared library:

```
module lib;

export extern(C) int abcd(){
    return 4;
}
```

it is compiled using `dmd -shared -m32 lib.d`, and the output is `lib.so`
And this is the code for the loader:

```
module loader;

import std.stdio;
import core.sys.posix.dlfcn;

alias func = extern(C) int function();

void main(string[] args){
    writeln("reached 0, press enter");readln;
    void* so = dlopen("/home/nafees/Desktop/temp/lib.so",RTLD_LAZY);
    writeln("reached 1, press enter");readln;
    func f = cast(func)dlsym(so,"abcd");
    writeln((*f)());
}
```

This one is compiled using `dmd -m32 loader.d`. It compiles fine, but when I run it, it runs fine till the `dlopen`, then causes a `segmentation fault(core dumped)`. This used to work fine on 32 bit.

What is wrong in this code, why won't it work?

P.S: I don't want to compile it for 64 bit, so if a solution requires removing `-m32`, I need another one.

EDIT: I have a program compiled (also written in D), that loads a shared object (which is also written in D), using dlopen. That program would run fine in 32 bit, but not on my 64 bit machine.

EDIT2: I now tried compiling the loader without -m32, it now dlerror is saying this: `/home/nafees/Desktop/temp/lib.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32`

Comment: Have you tried with other compilers, such as gcd?

Comment: Same problem with gdc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of dlopen try to use [loadLibrary](http://dlang.org/phobos/core_runtime.html#.Runtime.loadLibrary).

UPDATE:

Use -fPIC flags for compile lib.d:
dmd -m32 -fPIC -shared lib.d

Comment: This is what happens when I try using Runtime.loadLibrary:
nafees@OptiPlex-755:~/Desktop/temp$ dmd -m32 loader.d
loader.o: In function `_D4core7runtime7Runtime17__T11loadLibraryZ11loadLibraryFxAaZPv':
loader.d:(.text._D4core7runtime7Runtime17__T11loadLibraryZ11loadLibraryFxAaZPv+0x4d): undefined reference to `rt_loadLibrary'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
--- errorlevel 1`

Comment: try to build it with dmd -defaultlib=libphobos2.so

Comment: that would make a runtime dependency, I don't want that. Seems like D isn't runtime independent (I've been lied to).

Comment: what do you mean by runtime independent?

Comment: I mean that I would have to provide libphobos2.so along with my shared library. P.S; I tried that too, still the same problem...

Comment: OK, try it with -fPIC: dmd -fPIC -m32 -shared -defaultlib=libphobos2.so lib.d

Comment: It works!! I can't thank you enough! I've tried it without the `-defaultlib=libphobos2.so`, it is still working. Now if you could please post this as an answer, I'll accept it :)